# does indexOf() in JS search all the elements of an array to execute?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

```js
const arr = ['a','b','c']; 
for (let char of arr) {
  console.log(char);
}
```

I believe that time complexity of code above is O(n).

```js
const arr = ['a','b','c']; 
for (let char of arr) {
  console.log(arr.indexOf(char);
}
```

However, does indexOf() search all the elements?
If does so, I believe time complexity of code above may be O(n^2)

I want to know whether indexOf() searches all the components as for loop or not.

Comment: "...does indexOf() search all the elements?" All need to do is read this: [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, the complexity would be O(n^2), JavaScript engines are free to perform any optimisations they wish though, so it could be possible that in some implementations the `.indexOf()` method has had some fancy optimisations done to make it not search all elements (although, I'm not aware of any such optimisations). There are other data types such as Sets and Maps which the JS specification does say needs to have sublinear lookup, so you can be sure that the JS engines optimize those (in most cases they're optimised to be O(1) lookup for Sets/Maps (and also Objects))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For time complexity, you always consider the worst case (for the OP's circumstance, each character is in the list at no specifically designated position). To take OP example array, doing `arr.indexOf('c')` would involve looking at every position until the character `c` is found (which is the last position). Therefore, assuming worst case scenario, the execution would take `O(n)` time for `.indexOf()`. As per @Nick Parsons comment, there are ways to improve the time of the underlying search algorithm using strategies like a binary search (which is `O(log n)` time complexity), but that implies the data is in some semi-structured format for any concepts like binary search to improve the time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

If the browser vendors follow the language specification, then the answer is NO. It should return once a match is found. Under certain circumstances, it will return even without checking any elements. See [ECMA262](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.indexof).

However, complexity would be the same, O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `indexOf()` function has a complexity of O(n). If the provided index is negative, the array is still searched from front to back. If the calculated index is less than 0, then the whole array will be searched.

So your program will have big o notation of O(n^2)

You can find more about this here at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)